# Large distributed research network

Tags: computer-science, experiment-design

I remember having heard of a large distributed computer network being operated by several universities. As far as I remember, it would be possible to get several (hundreds) of virtual machines to perform computations, testing, evaluations, etc.

Unfortunately, I do not remember this network's name, but I have the feeling that it was similar to "ResearchLab" or "ScienceLab". However, I was not able to find a network with such a name...

Hope that anyone out there can help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There are several. And they come and go. This is too broad, really - it's a big-list question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're probably thinking of [PlanetLab](https://www.planet-lab.org/).

> PlanetLab is a global research network that supports the development of new network services. Since the beginning of 2003, more than 1,000 researchers at top academic institutions and industrial research labs have used PlanetLab to develop new technologies for distributed storage, network mapping, peer-to-peer systems, distributed hash tables, and query processing.
>
> PlanetLab currently consists of 1335 nodes at 645 sites.

More generally, there are lots of "testbeds" (as these networks of distributed resources are called), including Emulab, PlanetLab, ORBIT, DETER, Seattle, and many others. Each has various advantages and disadvantages, depending on what you're trying to do. These are often *federated* so that users can access resources from multiple testbeds; projects like GENI and FIRE are federations of testbeds.

Comment: Right... I'd forgotten about PlanetLab... do you know what its relation to the two projects that I mentioned is?

Comment: @jakebeal See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

I am currently aware of two large research networks of this type:

- [EmuLab](http://www.emulab.net/) allows experimentation with large numbers of virtual machines co-located within a facility at the University of Utah.
- [GENI](http://www.geni.net/) is a large-scale distributed networking testbed that also allows reconfiguration of the network switching hardware.

Both are primarily sponsored by the US National Science Foundation as public testbeds.  I have previously used EmuLab myself and found it delightfully easy to use.  I have not personally had an occasion to use GENI; the company I work for runs the GENI project office, though, and I hear that the testbed has been working out well.